# Menelaus theorem

Tags: geometry

Can someone give me the exact definition of the Menelaus' theorem. At some websites they say it is:
Given a triangle ABC, and a transversal line that crosses BC, AC and AB at points D, E and F respectively, with D, E, and F distinct from A, B and C, then $\frac{AF}{FB}*\frac{BD}{DC}*\frac{CE}{EA}=-1$. While others say it is:
Given a triangle ABC, and a transversal line that crosses BC, AC and AB at points D, E and F respectively, with D, E, and F distinct from A, B and C, then $\frac{AF}{FB}*\frac{BD}{DC}*\frac{CE}{EA}=1$. Which is the correct one and why is the other wrong?If both are correct,how are both correct?

Comment: First, it should be the product of the ratios. Also if the segments are directed then it is supposed to be -1.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake in my typing

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "if the segments are directed "

Comment: In directed segments we take $AB$ as $-BA$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I now understand the theorem better.